# Is the "Peek Definition" feature available in Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was eager to try the new "Peek Definition" feature in Visual Studio 2013, but I'm not able to find it anywhere in the program. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop, Version 12.0.21005.1 REL.

Is "Peek Definition" supposed to be available in Express versions?

Comment: Have you tried `Alt+F12`? This is the shortcut for Peek Definition

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to do anything. The right-click menu doesn't list it either and only has "Go To Definition". I also went to Tools->Customize->Keyboard and searched for Peek Definition but got no results. If I try to assign Alt+F12 to a random command, it doesn't say anything about the shortcut already being used.

Comment: Are you using C#, VB or C++?

Comment: I'd like to use it with a C++ project, but I've also tried creating both C# and VB projects and I still couldn't see Peek Definition mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Peek Definition just sits forever and paints a left to right animation on the top of its window.  Is Peek Definition incompatible with Resharper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple: <del>Peek definition is a VS Pro+ feature I saw it in a version table on the Microsoft site, but I can't find a link anymore. (comparing express vs Pro vs ..).</del>

**Edit as of 16.11.2014**: the new VS 2013 Community edition, which will replace the express edition longterm, does incorporate every feature the Pro edition does, so you get Peek definition for free (if you don't work on a closed source enterprise project in a company with more than 5 devs or more than 1 Mio. revenue/year).